# Decode JWT Token in Apex

Tags: apex, jwt

I am trying decode JWT token in apex, and i am not sure how that can be done. If anyone has done that before, please let me know the process.

A JWT token is sent to SFDC and need to decode it in apex class.

Questions:
1) Can we decode the JWT using any standard salesforce classes, if yes what class and method?
2) Or do we need to decode it with our custom code -- if so can you provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [EncodingUtil class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm) and `base64decode` to convert your encrypted string to a Blob. Once it's a Blob you can use `toString` to stringify it into a JSON string. You will need to know the algorithm used to encrypt the JWT initially as well as the key so that you can decrypt it. At that point there are JSON methods in Apex you can use to convert from a string to an object.

Comment: With JWT, the data itself is recoverable without any decryption. The encrypted bit allows you to verify that the actual JWT data wasn't modified and that it was generated by the person/entity that you expected (making it an HMAC, Hash-based Message Authentication Code, I think). A high-level description of the JWT format is `<base64URL encoded header> + '.' + <base64URL encoded claims> + '.' + <base64URL encoded hash of the base64URL encoded header + '.' + base64URL encoded claims>`

Comment: The other thing of note is that JWT uses [Base64URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), which Salesforce doesn't provide us any tools to handle directly. Base64URL just replaces "+" and "/" with "-" and "_" respectively; it's easy enough to do/undo with a couple of uses of the `replace()` method in the string class, but it is an extra step.